# create no-login user using chef

Tags: chef-infra

I read this https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html and looks like this is for creating the system account. But i want to create a user for running process with no login option. Right now, i am using execute block in my chef recipe. But i am not a great fan of execute block. Is there any way i can just replace this code?

```
execute 'create user for service' do
   command -c "This account is for testing something" -s /sbin/nologin -G 'myGroup' -r my_user'
end
```

Comment: I updated my answer, I did forget the `system true` to match your `-r` option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-s /sbin/nologin` on your command is the same as specifying `shell "/sbin/nologin"` in a user resource.

the `user` resource is to create users, it will create a system user if you set the `system` property to `true`.

so the Chef `user` resource for your command line is:

```rb
user 'my_user' do # the user name in your command
  action :create # default action, could be omitted, but better to precise it
  shell '/sbin/nologin'
  gid 'myGroup' # the -G in your execute
  comment 'This account is for testing somethin' # the -c in your execute
  system true # to match your -r in execute
  manage_home false # to avoid creating a home directory, omit if you wish it anyway
end
```

The `nologin` executable can be replaced by `false`. To find the correct path for your distro use `which nologin`.

Comment: It may be `/usr/sbin/nologin` on some distros, so be careful.

Comment: @sekrett I took the attributes from the question. Knowing which shell to use is out of scope for the answer. `/bin/false` is another option too.

Comment: Of course, the answer is right. On the other side the subject is about how to set nologin without specifying the distro, it may confuse somebody.

Comment: @sekrett I edited to add the precision, even if I find this off-topic as the question was more about the chef resource syntax.